# Div background color

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hell of a time trying to get a background color to show on a div. I have tried specifying width, height, overflow, etc. with no luck. The code is below. I can get inner div background to change, but not the containing div.

The div in question is **header-top-container**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
.header-top-container {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-top-container>.main-container {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

body .header-top-container .external-store-tab {
  width: 360px;
}

body .header-top-container .external-store-tab,
body .header-top-container .account-cart-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top-container">
  <div class="main-container header-main-container">
    <div class="external-store-tab">
      <div class="tab-item">
        <a href="https://www.example.org">
          <img src="https://www.example.org/logo-foundation.png" class="tab-logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-item active">
        <a href="http://store.example.org/">
          <img src="https://www.example.org/logo-store.png" class="tab-logo">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-cart-wrapper">
      <a href="http://www.example.org/contact/" class="account-link hide-mb">
        <span class="label" style="color:#008CA8;">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;
                    <span class="bar-text" tyle="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;">Contact</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a href="tel:800.222.5870" class="account-link">
        <span class="label" style="color:#008CA8;">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;
                    <span class="bar-text" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;">800.222.5870</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a href="https://store.example.org/customer/account/login/" class="skip-link skip-account account-link sign-in-bar">
        <span class="label">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;
                    <span class="bar-text" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;">Sign in</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a href="https://store.example.org/checkout/cart/" class="skip-link skip-account account-link">
        <span class="label">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background color for div with child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393322/background-color-for-div-with-child-divs)

Answer (score 0):

Add to class "header-top-container", property "position:inherit" class, like following:

```
.header-top-container {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I glad that I could help You

Comment: @D.F. Your answer would be much more helpful to the OP and future visitors if you could explain **why** your solution works. What is it correcting or doing that should have been done?

Answer (score -2):

Your #custom-layer1 has a background that matches the page. Your header-container-top is changing color, but is being 'painted' over so to speak by the background of #custom-layer1.

Comment: Thank you. While that works for the content section, it doesn't give me the full width background color I need.